# Spacewalk/Satellite Server - spacewalk-create-channel

Tags: linux, redhat, satellite, spacewalk

I have a Spacewalk installation and I have mirrored the RHEL6 base repo on my server using `mrepo`.

I created a channel using

```
spacewalk-create-channel --user=me --server=localhost --version=6 \
  --update=u2 --release=Server --arch=x86_64 --destChannel=rhel6u2  \
  -c rhel-x86_64-server-6
```

rhel-x86_64-server-6 has all the packages from Red Hat but when the rhel6u2 channel is created using the above command, it is missing the kernel packages. Also, it doesn't push all the packages that it says need to be pushed.

Here is the output:

> Trying with source channel: rhel-x86_64-server-6 Reusing rhel6u2 as
>   destination channel 3529 packages in source file to push. Pushing 2023
>   packages, please wait. Successfully pushed 2023 packages out of 3529

What am I missing? How do I get the kernel packages in?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while syncing, Try to check the Time/sync NTP in both sides, Maybe solve your problems.